# Does PowerMock class has expectNew method analog for method obtained object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

According this link:
[powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

If I have this class

```
public class PersistenceManager {

        public boolean createDirectoryStructure(String directoryPath) {
                File directory = new File(directoryPath);

                if (directory.exists()) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\"" + directoryPath + "\" already exists.");
                }

                return directory.mkdirs();
        }
}
```

I can test it following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( PersistenceManager.class )
public class PersistenceManagerTest {

        @Test
        public void testCreateDirectoryStructure_ok() throws Exception {
                final String path = "directoryPath";
                File fileMock = createMock(File.class);

                PersistenceManager tested = new PersistenceManager();

                expectNew(File.class, path).andReturn(fileMock);

                expect(fileMock.exists()).andReturn(false);
                expect(fileMock.mkdirs()).andReturn(true);

                replay(fileMock, File.class);

                assertTrue(tested.createDirectoryStructure(path));

                verify(fileMock, File.class);
        }
}
```

I have following question:

How Can I test this class:

```
public class PersistenceManager {

            public boolean createDirectoryStructure(String directoryPath) {
                    File directory = getFile(directoryPath);

                    if (directory.exists()) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("\"" + directoryPath + "\" already exists.");
                    }

                    return directory.mkdirs();
            }
            public File getFile(String directoryPath){
                return new File(directoryPath);
            }

    }
```

I use powerMock version 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Mockito`/`PowerMockito` you can use the `whenNew()` function.  It would probably look something like this once you expand it out a bit:

`PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withArguments(directoryPath).thenReturn((File) fileMock)`.

Also, when using `Mockito` try using `Mockito.mock()` to create the Mock objects (in this case `fileMock`.